# Accessing User Location in API 23 throws Security Exception Though Permissions Are Granted

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, android-location

I keep getting a security exception when trying to get location updates in API 23. The system seems to think I don't have the appropriate permissions:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Client must have ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to perform any location operations.
```

However, if I am checking for user location permissions before making the call to location services and both fine and coarse location are returning PERMISSION_GRANTED :

```
 private boolean locationPermissionsGranted(Context context){
    int fineLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    int coarseLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    return ((fineLocation == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) || (coarseLocation == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED));
}
```

I set permissions at runtime by prompting the user to grant permissions with the system dialog:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
            Permissions.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.getPermission());
```

I get the exception after permissions are granted because my boolean check for whether I have access to location returns true but the system wont let me access location. I'm testing this on a OnePlus One and started to think that maybe privacy guard was screwing with things but I've set it to allow access to location so I'm not sure why the error is persisting.

Comment: What is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: minSdkVersion 11 targetSdkVersion 23

Comment: Have you added the appropriate `<uses-permission>` elements to your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Comment: This is going to sound very dumb on my part, but I have seen people look right past the obvious and tear stuff up debugging.  Please take no offense.  Have you performed a clean build of your project?

Comment: @PabloBaxter Yeah I have. Still can't figure this out. I get the system pop up asking for location permissions, say yes, the system callback recognizes that the permission has been granted yet it says they haven't.

Comment: The code you provided above shows you are passing a context to the function.  Is that the same context that is requesting the permission?  Not that it should matter, but could be a weird bug.  Testing this myself out now.

Comment: Another thing that may be helpful, does this happen on only one phone, or all phones?  Can you give phone make and model?

Comment: @PabloBaxter I'm using a OnePlus One I don't have another phone running API 23 to test this on a real device.

Comment: @PabloBaxter I'll check if the context is the same but it's just checking whether the permission is granted (returns a 1 or 0 I think) so that method shouldn't affect access to the locations.

Comment: I agree.  This almost makes me think it is a phone issue, but I'd like to see more code first.  Possibly even a demo APK with the same code logic that will cause this issue, so I can test it on some of the phones I have.  Can you post some information about the class that is passing the context to the "locationPermissionGranted" function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118659/discussion-between-pablo-baxter-and-rarw).

Comment: Not a clear solution here but I was previously running the phone without a SIM card just as a test device. Once I put a SIM card in the phone, location services started working. It is unclear why this would be the case since devices without a SIM card, like a tablet, should still be able to get location services. But that is what happened.

Answer (score -2):

[Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. This approach streamlines the app install process, since the user does not need to grant permissions when they install or update the app.

You need to request the access location permission and handle the request response at app runtime

Comment: Read the posting. I am requesting at runtime and handling the response. The permissions are being granted. The issue is that I'm getting a security excpetion even though check permissions returns permission granted.